# Date range query not working on elastic 2.4 cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range, elasticsearch-query

Elasticsearch query with date range query isn't working.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "100",
            "fields": [
              "nodeId"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "DAILY",
            "fields": [
              "aggLevel"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "23",
            "fields": [
              "replId"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "sales.date": {
              "gte": "01-02-2020",
              "lte": "08-03-2020"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, so that you don't get downvotes and community can help you efficiently :)

Comment: In reference to elasticsearch questions, you should always provide your index mapping, sample indexed documents and your expected result(in case of not expected output) and in case of error or exceptions, you should provide the stacktrace and clearly mention which one of these two you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format, the correct one is `yyyy-mm-dd` while you are using `dd-mm-yyyy`. Please refer [date data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/date.html#date) and [date range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) ES doc for more information.

Correct example

### Index mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "sales_date": {
                    "type": "date"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample docs

```
{
   "sales_date" :  "01-02-2020"
}

{
   "sales_date" :  "2020-02-05"
}

{
   "sales_date" :  "2020-03-08"
}
{
   "sales_date" :  "2020-03-15"
}
```

### Search query with `date range query`

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "sales_date" : {
                "gte" : "2020-02-01", --> NOTE DIFFERENCE
                "lte" : "2020-03-01"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search results

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-60584496",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "sales_date": "2020-02-01"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60584496",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "sales_date": "2020-02-05"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Not yet. You are right, that is default format of date but I have already given the date format through mappings.                                                                                                       { "settings" : {
       "number_of_shards" : 3,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    },"mappings" : {
     "_default_":{
        "properties" : {
            "sales" : { "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
            "date":    { "type": "date", "format": "dd-MM-yyyy"},
            "sales": { "type": "float"  }
            } }}}}}

Comment: yes, range query will not work on nested date. It is working, if I am using non nested date

Answer (score 0):

For me, range query worked on a non-nested date with mappings:

```
  "mappings": {
            "_default_": {
                "properties": {
                    "date": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "MM-dd-yyyy"
                            }
                      }
            }}
```

Working query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "100",
            "fields": [
              "nodeId"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "DAILY",
            "fields": [
              "aggLevel"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "23",
            "fields": [
              "replId"
            ],
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "01-02-2020",
              "lte": "08-03-2020"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```